# How to run grails in Netbeans (8.0) with https (ssl)?

Tags: grails, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 8.0 to develop a Grails 2.3.7 application.  How do I run the development environment using SSL?  I know about the command line option for grails

```
grails run-app -https
```

but I do not see where in Netbeans I would put this option for Grails.  Perhaps there is a different way to configure the Grails development environment to use SSL all together.

I have the grails app configured in Netbeans and Netbeans can run the app on the default port 8080 without SSL.  The Grails icon appears to the left of the project in the "Projects" window.  Everything seems to be configured correctly for the default operations, i.e., the application runs and works.

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on your Project in Netbeans and select the Run/Debug Grails Command option.

A window will get open.

Select the command you want to run (i.e, run-app).

write the **-https** parameter in the Parameters field and hit run button.

Comment: This works and it is what I'm currently doing.  But it seems contrary to the way IDE's should work.  I would like to be able to press the "Run" button in Netbeans and have it automatically add `-https` to the run-app command.  For Gradle projects I can do stuff like this.  Same for Java projects.  Why not Grails? Or rather, is it really not possible to do this with Grails projects in Netbeans?